# Convert DataTable to List<double> in R.NET

Tags: c#, r

I'm trying to make a project using backend R and frontend C# using R.NET connector.
I want to convert a DataTable to a List and then convert it to NumericMatrix, because R can't process DataTable.

But when the following line is reached:

```
double r = Convert.ToDouble(row);
```

Iget this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

This is my code:

```
NumericMatrix matadata;
int nkolom = dataawal.Columns.Count;
if (nkolom > 1)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < nkolom; j++)
    {
        int kol = dataawal.Columns[j].Ordinal;
        List<double> s = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataawal.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            String row = dataawal.Rows[i].ItemArray[kol].ToString();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                double r = Convert.ToDouble(row); // NOTE Error comes here!
                s.Add(r);
            }
        }
        String nokol = Convert.ToString(j + 1);
        NumericVector v = engine.CreateNumericVector(s);
        engine.SetSymbol("dum", v);
        matadata = engine.Evaluate("matdt=matrix(cbind(matdt,dum),ncol=" + nokol + ")").AsNumericMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: This means that your row variable contains something that cannot be converted to a double. You should use double.TryParse in this situation. If you start the debugger and look what values are passed to the row variable you could easily understand your problem

Comment: Yes, my row variable actually contain , (comma) as a decimal separator. Is that why I got an error?

Comment: It depends. What is the exact value of the row variable at the time when the error occurs? You should be able to see it when debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when you are uncertain about the correctness of a string value representing a double value you should resort to [double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). This method doesn't throw an exception if the string cannot be recognized as a valid double, instead it return false and you are able to skip (or assume zero) the offending row.

Something like this

```
...
else
{
    double r;
    // if tryparse returns true then r has received the converted value
    if(double.TryParse(row, out r))
        s.Add(r);
}
...
```

However you could have other problems like a value that is a valid double but expressed with a decimal formatting not valid for your current locale settings. In this case you need a different form of double.TryParse. The one that accepts also an instance of a class that implements the `IFormatProvider` interface.

For example, assuming that your wanna be doubles are formatted using the `it-IT` locale (where a comma delimits the integer part from the decimal) then you should use

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT");

...
else
{
    double r;
    if(double.TryParse(row, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out r))
        s.Add(r);
}
...
```